# PHP 7.1 uninstall on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, php7

I had a few troubles installing php7.1 on my OS Ubuntu 14.04

So I downloaded the php-7.1.11.tar.gz (sig) [18, 995Kb] version from: http://php.net/downloads.php

I install it using the following instructions:

```
tar -xzf archive-name.tar.gz
cd archive-name
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Now I would like to remove it, but I don't know how.

I ran:

```
php apt-get purge php7.*
```

However if I run `php -v` , I still get:

```
PHP 7.1.11 (cli) (built: Nov 17 2017 11:35:49) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

If I run PHP --ini, I get

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

I go into `/usr/local/lib`, and I don't see anything. I even revealed hidden files

---

UPDATE

I ran `locate php7.1`, I got:

```
locate php7.1
/var/cache/apt/archives/libapache2-mod-php7.1_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-bz2_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-cli_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-common_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-curl_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-gmp_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-intl_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-json_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-mbstring_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-mcrypt_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-mysql_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-opcache_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-readline_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-sqlite3_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-tidy_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-xml_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1-zip_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/php7.1_7.1.11-1+0~20171027135825.10+jessie~1.gbp2e638d_all.deb
/var/log/php7.1-fpm.log
/var/log/upstart/php7.1-fpm.log.1.gz
/var/log/upstart/php7.1-fpm.log.2.gz
/var/log/upstart/php7.1-fpm.log.3.gz
/var/log/upstart/php7.1-fpm.log.4.gz
/var/log/upstart/php7.1-fpm.log.5.gz
/var/log/upstart/php7.1-fpm.log.6.gz
/var/log/upstart/php7.1-fpm.log.7.gz
```

Comment: I tried the steps there, but it still does not work. I will update my question with the steps

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) on how to format your post.

Comment: Please run `sudo make uninstall` from `archive-name.tar.gz` to remove it!

Comment: @George Here is what I get:

**make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.**

Comment: Did you not install it from there previously?

Comment: @George Yes I did.  But from what i read, php does not have an uninstall option

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can remove compiled binary if the authors doesn't provide a `make uninstall` target for it. If that compiled binaries are located in a single directory by any chance, like `/usr/local/php7.1` or something, you can remove the whole directory. To get the directory from which php command is running, type `ls -l $(which php)` and if it is a symbolic link, follow that link to get to that directory from which php command is running. Most likely you will find some or all of the files installed by `make install` command in that directory.